# I'm trying to get the last version of my code on git

Tags: git

I'm trying to get the last version of the master code on my local machine without deleting any current work that's being done in the later part of the tree. How do I accomplish this in git?

[image]

I want my local machine to have the code at the 'new items' version without deleting those changes that are happening in the master version above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close any open editors that will complain if you change files out from under them.

Stash changes (in files Git is tracking) since the last commit:

```
git stash
```

Checkout the commit made before the last commit on the master branch:

```
git checkout master^
```

Done!

To get back to where you started:

```
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

Check out this awesome [Git book](http://book.git-scm.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
git stash
git stash pop
```

to save and restore your working directory.

If you have some commits that are not pushed and will cause a merge conflict, use

```
git rebase
```

This will save any commits not yet pushed, fetch the latest code, apply it, and then put the saved commits on top of the newest commits. And you're done.

EDIT: If you want to avoid the merge conflicts with code already committed, then use

```
git reset --soft
```

That'll take all committed but not yet pushed code and put it back in the index. Then you can stash that, and pull from master.

Comment: I don't think `rebase` fetches the latest code. And there were some conflicts when doing merge, they will appear when using rebase as well.

Comment: I don't believe that `rebase` does the fetching. @sciritai was highlighting the code to go around the `fetch`. i.e. `stash` it, `fetch`, `pop`, and then maybe `rebase`, as required.